# HugSQL defined function not found

Tags: clojure, user-defined-functions, hugsql

This will probably be very thin but I am running out of options...

I am using clojure with hugsql and I am a true beginner with database tech. I am trying to call an user-defined function that a colleague has defined in the database.

So, my problem is: making the query in databases software such as dbeaver, I get the results with no issues, however running from hugsql I get an error claiming it does not recognize the function.

My .sql file is something like

```sql
-- :name a-fake-name :? :1
-- :doc some fake documentation

select * from a_fake_user_defined_function(:arg1, :arg2, :arg3, :arg4, 1);
```

I read the queries like so

```clj
(ns sql.commands
  (:require [hugsql.core :as hugsql]))

(hugsql/def-db-fns "sql/file.sql")
```

I runned the command from clojure:

```clj
(def db
  {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
   :subprotocol "postgresql"
   :subname subname
   :user user
   :password password})

(sql/a-fake-name db {:arg1 "first-argument" :arg2 "second-one" :arg3 "third" :arg4 "and-forth"})
```

And the error I get is

```
ERROR: function a_fake_user_defined_function(character varying,
   character varying, character varying, character varying, integer)
   does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and
   argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
   Position: 15
```

From the error I assume, I am missing some notation or configuration... Does anyone have an idea on what I can do?

I tried to look on [hugsql documentation](https://www.hugsql.org/) but got no luck.

Thx!

PS.: I am well aware it is a good practice provide an reproducible error on stackoverflow, but this is from my work I am quite clueless on how to reproduce the database. Hopefully this is enough...

Comment: The error looks like from pg - is the function there with this name? does it have the same arguments? Can you call your function there with four varchars and an int outside of hugsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted by @cfrick, the problem was with the arguments definition in the hugsql file. The answer was also provided by a contributor in a [github issue](https://github.com/layerware/hugsql/issues/128).

The problem was that it was not finding a function with that name and those type of arguments. The solution then was to type cast with double-colon each of the arguments (https://www.hugsql.org/#colon).